# How to remove border of card view with jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I am facing the issue of border remove from card view in jetpack compose.
Kindly guide me on how to do achieve border removal from card view functionality.
My code is below but not working correctly.

**Code**

```
Card(
    shape = RoundedCornerShape(0.dp),
    border = BorderStroke(0.dp, Transparent),
    modifier = Modifier
        .height(100.dp)
        .padding(start = 10.dp, top = 40.dp, end = 10.dp)
        .border(0.dp, Transparent),
) {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .clickable {
                submit()
            },
    ) {
        Text(
            modifier = Modifier
                .weight(1f)
                .padding(start = 20.dp, top = 20.dp, bottom = 20.dp)
                .wrapContentWidth(Alignment.Start),
            text = "Submit",
            style = typography.h4,
        )
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: What is your expected UI result? can you post an image?

Comment: Yes. I will attach

Comment: @MuhammadZaryabRafique, Is the requirement "to remove the border"?

Comment: Why do you need a card if you want to remove the elevation, the rounded corners and the borders?

Answer (score 5):

Actually, By default, there is no border in Card. What you are seeing is 1.dp elevation. So if you don't want any elevation make it 0.dp like the following.

```
Card(
    modifier = Modifier
        .height(100.dp)
        .padding(start = 10.dp, top = 40.dp, end = 10.dp),
    elevation = 0.dp
) {
    Your content..
}
```